# Main Menu not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I just set up a WordPress theme but I am seeing that the Main menu is not showing up. Even after assigning the "Main Menu" location to my menu, it still isn't showing up.

However, assigning my menu to the "Top Bar Menu" shows my menu in the top bar without struggles.

Any solution for showing my menu in the "Main Menu" position?

Comment: what is the code you did? How you have used the wp_navmenu function please share the code than we can help.

Answer (score 1):

check if the template give you choose to select default or custom style because if the template has default style chois. your changes not be displaying

Comment: I set the header layout to centred(instead of standard, another option) and it showed the menu! centralized. So the menu cannot be aligned right in this theme?

Answer (score 1):

If main menu is not displaying then you can create the new custom main menu.

For that, add this function in `function.php` file :

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu' => 'Main Menu'
    )
);
```

Comment: This actually did remove a burden from me. But how do I style it to bring it to the right and change its appearance? sorry if it is a noob question.

Answer (score -3):

In order for the wordpress menu to show at the top of the page, you must be logged in as a site admin. That menu does not show for all site users, only admins who are logged in to the site. In order to change your theme you had to log in, which would have made the menu appear on the page even if you hadn't switched themes and switched back.

For More Accurate answer share your code to get exact idea.

I hope this link will definitely help you

https://www.icozens.com/solved-wordpress-menu-items-not-showing/